# check if whole block has any childs with inner text

Tags: python, css, selenium, xpath, parent-child

using selenium webdriver i faced with the problem to find block that has childrens with inner text.

```
<div class="chat_dialog">
 <div class="chat_message">
  <span class="chat_timestamp" style="display: none;">[14:55:24]</span>
  <span class="sender persona online">zajac</span></div>
 </div>
 <div class="chat_message">
  <span class="chat_timestamp" style="display: none;">[14:55:25]</span>
  <span class="sender persona online">othername</span></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

i need to select block with class **.chat_dialog** has **zajac**

**driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.chat_dialog ').text** doesn't working as I suspected. i know i can find all elements with class **sender** but i need othe way!
may be i can do this with xpath or css selectors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Webdriver.find_element_by_xpath`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_element_by_xpath) with following xpath expression:

```
xpath = './/div[@class="chat_dialog"][descendant::text()="zajac"]'
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
```

`[descendant::text()="zajac"]` will filter descendant element whose text is `zajac`.

Comment: thanks, it works) and how i can check - if **chat_dialog** has my text or no ?               `if len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath('.//div[@class="chat_dialog_content"][descendant::text()="' + driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#chat_page_header_user  div div.friendslist_entry_content span.linkFriend').text + '"]')) !=0:`    doesn't working(..i need to check if page has this block with this text or no.

Comment: @RomaPerfilyev, It's hard to read the code in the comment. Please post separated question with the code.